# Drupal: how to add menu link to password change?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-navigation

**Do You have any idea how to easily add a menu link "Change Your password" that would lead to Edit Profile page?**

I can programmatically add it, but I hoped that in the Admin Panel I could add a link, like `[drupal]/user/edit` that would redirect me to `[drupal]/user/[id]/edit`.

The best solution that comes to my mind is to create a site i.e.`[drupal]/password` that would contain a code adding user id and redirecting to its profile edit page.

But maybe You know a solution that would work out of the box?

PS It seems that often Drupal makes complex things easy, but sometimes it does the other way round. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [me](http://drupal.org/project/me) module solves this.